Not able to login to mongo express
I'm running mongo and mongo express using below docker-compose file. My code was able to connect to the database and create a record. When I try to login to mongo express using a browser, it is not accepting root as username and password.
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://root:root@mongo:27017/

